# probability of the sum of i.i.d. RV with uniform distribution being $>x$

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

I am solving a question for applied stochastic processes homework and I am stuck on this part:

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n$ be independent identically distributed random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Let $0<x<1$. 
I need to find $$\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_n<x \mid X_1+\cdots +X_{n-1}<x).$$

I think that the answer should be $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\cdots+X_n<x \mid X_1+\cdots +X_{n-1}<x)=\frac{x}{n}$,  for reasons of symmetry , since we have $n$ RV then each of them in average should be less then $\frac{x}{n}$  so that the total sum is less then $x$. Is my guess correct? And how can I state it in more mathematical basis?

Comment: So you don't know anything about the $X_i$ (they are not uniform, just iid?) and you want something explicit, i.e. not just a bound?

Comment: they have uniform distribution,wrote that in the title but forgot to write it in the question. And yes I want something explicit, just a bound wouldn't make it.

Comment: The sum of $n$ iid uniform RV is something called an [Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). Looks pretty horrible.

Comment: I saw that but its really too complicated. It should be something more combinatorial to get the answer

Comment: Actually, since you're only considering $x \in (0, 1)$ it's pretty simple.

Comment: any hints? @Tyler

Comment: If you need to derive it on your own, no clue. Looking at the wikipedia page there's an obvious pattern that agrees with your hunch, though. Like I said, seems like a nasty problem. Maybe try using convolutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{P}(S_{n} < x)
&= \Bbb{P}(S_{n-1} < x - X_{n} \,;\, X_{n} < x) \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \Bbb{P}(S_{n-1} < x - y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \Bbb{P}(S_{n-1} < y) \, dy.
\end{align*}

Since $\Bbb{P}(S_{1} < x) = x$, by induction we can easily check that

$$ \Bbb{P}(S_{n} < x) = \frac{x^{n}}{n!}. $$

In particular, you get

$$ \Bbb{P}(S_{n} < x \mid S_{n-1} < x) = \frac{x}{n}. $$

Comment: pretty clear and elegant, thnx!

Comment: @Albanian_EAGLE Thank you! I would also like to comment that it works only for $0 < x < 1$. Otherwise you will get something nasty as in that Wikipedia article.

Comment: do you think there exist an elegant way to compute the Var[S_n]?